# Find coding errors and bad coding practice in php code

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and I have faced an interview some days ago. They gave me a PHP code to find out the errors and bad programming practices. I have pointed out some of the errors and bad practices. But I am not sure about all the bugs in the code. Can you please help me to find out the exact answer, so I can improve my answer in the next interviews.

My suggestions are:

- Include an external PHP file based on user request is not a good practice
- HTML is mixed with PHP, not using MVC architecture style
- Writing connection query in same file
- is_authorized() function is not defined
- mysql_connect is deprecated, can use mysqli

Here is the code

```
<?php
function output()
{
// Check authorization
if(is_authorized())
{
$authorized = true;
include('/path/to/' . $_REQUEST['module'] . '.php');
}
    echo "<ul>";
    $conn = mysql_connect( "mysql.foo.org:324", "root", "root" );
    mysql_select_db( "conteol", $conn ); // selects a database
    $q = " SELECT * FROM main WHERE id > " . $_GET["id"]. ";";
    $res = mysql_query( $q, $conn);
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $res ) )
    {
        echo "<li>".$row['description']."</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul><br><ul>";
    $q = " SELECT * FROM main WHERE id < " . $_GET["id"]. ";";
    $res = mysql_query( $q, $conn);
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $res ) )
    {
    $authorized = true;
    include('/path/to/' . $_REQUEST['module'] . '.php');
    echo "<li>".$row['description']."</li>";
    // Display the status if it is authorized, othewise display N/A
    echo "<li>".$row['description']. "(" .
        $authorized ? $row['status'] : "N/A" . ")</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
?>
```

Comment: The major problem is the risk of SQL injection. And gave up mysql_*. Use PDO or mysqli_* with [prepared statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)

Comment: As @Debflav said, as soon as you see `mysql_` you should think Alert!. That is probably one of the most extended, biggest problems in php.

Answer (score 0):

Some more thoughts:

- Using `$_GET['id']` directly in an SQL query is not a good idea. You should probably call `intval()` on it.
- Using `$row['description']` directly for output is not a good idea. You should probably call `htmlspecialchars()` on it.
- `$authorized=true;` is set in the code in the while loop without calling `is_authorized()`
- `include('/path/to/' . $_REQUEST['module'] . '.php');` is called in the while loop. Should be called outside the loop. Maybe, `include_once()` is a better idea.
- The whole code is executed even if `is_authorized()` returns false.

Answer (score 0):

I could add some more to that list:

- Poor/inconsistent indentation
- Inconsistent formatting
- Undescriptive variables name
- Security vulnerability using `$_REQUEST` in `include`
- Open to SQL injections using `$_GET` in SQL queries

Being somebody who has interviewed for new PHP developers myself, it is the security issues that I would have really been looking for.

Answer (score 0):

- Formatting/indentation is terrible
- `$_REQUEST` should never be used, always use the method-specific array
- No error checking for mysql connection
- No SQL injection protection
- Do not use include, use include_once
- Double MYSQL query for basically the same check: using `WHERE id != $id` would also work
- Authorisation in second loop is always set to true
- Displaying "N/A" for something you don't have access to is pointless.